# How to chain multiple assertThat statement in AssertJ

Tags: assertj

Here is an example:

```
assertThat(commentById.getId()).isNotNull();
assertThat(commentById.getContent()).isNotBlank();
assertThat(commentById.getAuthor()).isNotNull();
assertThat(commentById.getAuthor().getUsername()).isNotBlank();
assertThat(commentById.getAuthor().getAvatar()).isNotBlank();
assertThat(commentById.getAuthor().getId()).isNotNull();
```

Is there anyway to chain this into a single `assertThat` statement

---

Sorry for the unclear question. I mean, is there some fluent method calls to chain multiple assertThat statement together. Here is an example I can think of:

```
assertThat(commentById)
.isNotNull()
.and(Comment::getID).isNotNull()
.and(Comment::getContent).isNotBlank()
.and(Comment::getAuthor).is(author->{
         author.isNotNull()
        .and(User::getID).isNotNull()
        .and(User::getAvatar).isNotBlank()
        .and(User::getUsername).isNotBlank()
});
```

Comment: How would "chaining" these statements help you?

Comment: Please provide a sample of what you think it should do.

Comment: sorry for the unclear question. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment, what is possible is to use [`extracting`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#extracting-java.util.function.Function-) but that implies navigating from the current actual to the extracted one without being able to go back to the original actual.

Answer (score 18):

You can utilize `satisfies` method:

```java
assertThat(commentById.getId()).isNotNull();
assertThat(commentById.getContent()).isNotBlank();
assertThat(commentById.getAuthor()).isNotNull().satisfies(author -> {
    assertThat(author.getUsername()).isNotBlank();
    assertThat(author.getAvatar()).isNotBlank();
    assertThat(author.getId()).isNotNull();
});
```

This helps to eliminate repeating parts of code while testing nested structures.

If you want the `commentById` object itself to be tested by "one-liner", it is theoretically possible to apply same approach onto it (`assertThat(commentById).satisfies(c -> {assertThat(c.getId()).isNotNull(); ...})`), however I state it here only to literally answer your question, actually I don't see any benefit of such expression.

Comment: Thanks, didn't came across this, just now.